# Unable to save image file in android oreo update. How to do it?

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I can't save an image file in android oreo(8.0) api 26.
The code is working perfectly in api level 25 (7.0) and I didn't find any changes in the documentation "[Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)"

Here is my code

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
File myrootDir = new File(root);
if (!myrootDir.exists()) {
    myrootDir.mkdir();
}

File myDir = new File(root + "/Myimages");
if (!myDir.exists()) {
    myDir.mkdir();
}
final String fname = System.currentTimeMillis()+"myimage.png";
File file = new File(myDir, fname);
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}catch (Exception e){
   Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
}
```

Exception is FileNotFoundException, No such file or directory. (But Why not in android n ?)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Myimages/1513151272243myimage.png (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:17:52.243 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
12-13 13:17:52.243 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
12-13 13:17:52.243 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
12-13 13:17:52.243 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
12-13 13:17:52.243 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at com.package.package.DetailPage$12.run(DetailPage.java:737)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
12-13 13:17:52.244 5839-5839/com.package.package W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Do you have any exceptions? Please post it here

Comment: Oohh I see you have an empty catch block, Please add some logging into the catch block. As a Best Practice, **never leave the catch block empty. Always handle it**

Comment: i can save image using this code in android n. but in android o, nop :(

Comment: @MikeM. check the edit.

Comment: @Rinav thanks for indicating that

Comment: ok let me try that wait.

Comment: Same as i mentioned in the edit. FileNotFoundException, (No such file or directory)

Comment: no, not `e.printStackTrace();`. In android we generally use `Log.e("TAG", message, e)` to capture exceptions

Comment: just post the entire stack trace

Comment: @Rinav check the edit

Comment: @MikeM. i requested  READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the previous page. Documentation says : the system grants only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that time; however, if the app later requests WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the system immediately grants that privilege without prompting the user.

Comment: @MikeM. ok let me try that. pls wait.

Comment: @MikeM. It worked. GIve it as aswer i will accpet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is, in fact, a slight, subtle change in Permissions for apps running on and targeting API 26.

Previously, apps were automatically granted all permissions in a given group if at least one permission in that group had been granted by the user. This means that an app that had been granted the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` would've had `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` immediately granted to it as well, regardless of whether `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` had been explicitly requested.

As of Oreo, for apps targeting API 26+, this has been corrected, and only those permissions that are explicitly requested will be granted. If the user has already granted a permission in the same group, then there will be no prompt for the new permission, but it still must be requested.

That was the problem, in this case. When the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission was granted to your app on Nougat or below, you were automatically getting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, too, without having to request that one specifically. When you try the same file save procedure in Oreo, you aren't getting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` automatically, so the write ultimately fails.

Simply add a specific request for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. If the user has already granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, they won't be bothered with another prompt. Alternatively, you could request solely `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from the start, which implicitly includes `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and would save you the need for two separate requests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383849/java-io-filenotfoundexception-no-such-file-or-directory-error Could you look this question?

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing the same issue and i am stuck with this issue from 2 months. I have already given permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest first and also again checking is it have write permission. I think it is not a permission issue. Because when i test with oreo the folder is creating and there is a corrupted image file in the folder i am creating. Because of that it is not coming to the gallery and then on save it returns me Image not captured. I am getting this problem only in android 7.1.1 and oreo. Upto android 7.0 it is working fine. I have checked with devices samsung galaxy note 8 and google pixel xl 2. I am using a custom camera with with gps and below function

```
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
```

for image byte save and the save function contains the code below

```
OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(finalFile);
                        output.write(bytes);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != output) {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
```