# Failed to create Directory in Oreo (API 26)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, create-directory

**I am trying to create a directory in Oreo but its failed.but working fine in Nougat and below.**
I have added Runtime Storage Permission already.

```
        File myDir = null;
        boolean status = false;
        File downloadedImage;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mediaUrl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/RealInstagram/media/");
            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }
         }
```

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` check the return value. `if ( !myDir.mkdirs()) return;`. You could also add a toast there.

Comment: `"/RealInstagram/media/"` That should be `"RealInstagram/media"`.

Comment: @greenapps I checked    (!myDir.mkdirs()) ,every times its returnig  "false"

Comment: Well what did you do with my other remark?

Comment: Even after this "RealInstagram/media" . its failure to create directory @greenapps

Comment: if (!myDir.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(StoryActivity.this, "Directory not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                } .Everytime giving Toast and after that not able to create directory

Comment: Pretty bad code. You should have `if (!myDir.mkdirs()) { Toast.makeText(StoryActivity.this, "Could not create directory: " + myDir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); return;}`.

Comment: Did you explicitly request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at runtime? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788508

Comment: Thanks  @MikeM. It works.