# mkdirs doesn't work on Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm trying to run simple code to create a directory on the external storage picture directory. 
On 8.1.0 mkdirs keeps returning false and the directory is not created. On 7.1.1 it works just fine.
Here's my code:

```
    private void initializePhotoStorageDirectory() {
    photoStorageDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "FolderName");

    if (!photoStorageDirectory.exists()) {
        photoStorageDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

I declare the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and I made sure the permission is granted during testing and, as I mentioned above, it's working on 7.1.1, so this doesn't looks like a permissions issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you explicitly request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at runtime? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788508

Comment: Yap, I tried that too. Nothing different.

Comment: Ohhh, wait, I guess I didn't do it explicitly. I seems to be working now.
Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll approve.

Comment: Ah, cool. Actually, the answer here would be pretty much exactly the same, and the linked one is my answer, anyway, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!